# form interaction, setter should get a delay

Tags: forms

Im trying to do an Highscore in a game. So if the game is running and the Highscore is at first at 0. After the games end (20 sec) the highscore should look if the points are higher and if it should update it and give this information to the other form, sadly its just giving me the highscore 0. I though about that I should delay something that it updating the highscore

thats my first form1:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (numberE < 5)
        {
            swi = 0;
            Füttern f = new Füttern();
            f.Show();
            this.Hide();
            timer9.Start();
            label6.Text = (++numberE).ToString();
            tim = 1; 
            label1.Text = f.Highsco.ToString();

}
```

}

and thats the form with the points and Highscore:

```
 int Zeit = 20;
        int Punkte = 0;
        private int Highsc = 10;

    public int Highsco
    {

        get { return Highsc;}
        set { Highsc = value;}
    }

    private void button1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = dog.Location.X;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) x = 712;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) x = 65;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S) x = 350;
        dog.Location = new Point(x, 420);
    }
    Random r = new Random();


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Burger.Visible = true;
        int random = r.Next(1, 4);
        int c = Burger.Location.X;
        if (random == 1) c = 65;
        else if (random == 2) c = 712;
        else if (random == 3) c = 350;
        Burger.Location = new Point(c, 0);



    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int y = Burger.Location.Y +40;
        if (Burger.Location.X == 65) Burger.Location = new Point(65, y);
        else if (Burger.Location.X == 350) Burger.Location = new Point(350, y);
        else if (Burger.Location.X == 712) Burger.Location = new Point(712, y);

        if (dog.Location.X == Burger.Location.X && dog.Location.Y == Burger.Location.Y - 20)
        {
            Punkte = Punkte + 1;
            label1.Text = Highsc.ToString();
            if(Punkte> Highsc)
            {
                Highsc = Punkte;
            }

            Burger.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Zeit > 0)
            label2.Text = (--Zeit).ToString();

        else
        {
            this.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Du hast " + Punkte + " erreicht!");

        }

    }


}
```

}

so how I can manage it that the Highscore are sure the Highscore?